# how to access firefox tab attributes via javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to **remove** visited attribute from a browser tab after AJAX call finishes ...

Once this is done the [Tab Mix Plus](http://tmp.garyr.net/) will then highlight this tab in different colour so I don't have to wait for the AJAX call to be finished.

I was [told in forum](http://tmp.garyr.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=47310#47310) what to do but I do not know how. And because Mr.Google didn't give any answer I created this question.

Any idea how to access browser tabs attributes from javascript? I do not want to **refresh** the whole page though.

Comment: by tabs, you mean the browser tabs? and what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: so, what you want to do is update a javascript attribute of something generated by Tab Mix Plus, right? I would recommend responding to the forum post with something like "how do I access the javascript tab attributes? I'm stumped"

Comment: I thought it would be `a standard` javascript thing ...

Comment: I think chances are that the guy posting there claiming it can be done has no idea what he's talking about. :)

Comment: let us see his answer...

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove visited attribute from a tab after AJAX call finishes ...

I don't think this is possible.

A hacky workaround idea would be adding a query parameter to the link:

```
<a href="index.htm">
```

would e.g. become

```
<a href="index.htm?192389290348243">
```

of course, this disables caching for these resources.

Comment: I updated my question with the link to the TMP forum where I was told that I can do that via javascript....